# AngularJs Routes and Refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

**Routes** is what I am using in AngularJs to load dynamic content through an ajax calls asynchronously. This is how I do that:

```
var $app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

$app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/pop", {controller: "popCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/pop_test.html"})
    .when("/dashboard", {controller: "dashBoardCtrl", templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html"})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/"})

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

I also have a mini nav set up so that when I click on my links it loads those partials through the **templatrUrl parameter**

```
   <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pop">Pop</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
   </ul>
```

This is all working great, when I click on my links it loaded the content I have set up in **pop_test.html** and **dashboard.html**

> Now the problem that I am having.

When you click on the link for lets say dashboard the content loads just fine through *ng-view* and the routes work great BUT if the user **reloads or refreshes** the page and you're on lets say ***localhost/dashboard*** it will actually try to go to that link and locate a file named after whatever you have after / which in this case is a directory called dashboard.

So how can I make it so when the user refreshes or reloads the page he doesn't actually reload the /dashboard page therefor not getting a server error page not found.

Comment: If you're using `html5 mode` then you need to have server configuration for the refresh/initial loading. It's impossible not to call the server each time a user refresh/reload the page.

Comment: I dont understand, you want to NOT refresh the page when the user clicks refresh? and why is refresh different from the regular page entry? are you passing some data that you loose?

Comment: @ Alberto I.N.J what do you mean about server configuration?

Comment: @ Jony-Y Because the URL only looks like it changed but it really didn't go anywhere, the content on the other pages are loaded through Ajax on the same page. So because routes would make the URL look like 'localhost/dashboard' when loading the partial is loaded if you were to hit refresh it will actually try to locate a dashboard.html which does not exist in that directory. Only within a partials folder that I am loading part of the html from.

Comment: didnt get you sorry, if the url changed then your controller is called since its connected to that route and the html is rendered... what do you mean only looks like it changed? can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alberto mentioned, the server needs to know what to do. In Angular's case, everything needs to be routed through the `index.html` when using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` otherwise you'll run into what you are now.

To fix this you need to add a Server Rewrite rule which you can find an explanation of it, along with the different server versions, in [ui-router's docs here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

You can also add a `.htaccess` file with the rewrite rules for `index.html` like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried making a .htaccess file with this in it and it gives me this error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @LucasSantos Is your `index.html` and your `.htaccess` file in the root app folder? You need to make sure the last line is pointing to your index file.

Comment: I replaced /index.html with just / and it worked. Thanks a ton @Shane !